# MySQL sql data text languages (japanese, greek, etc...)

Tags: mysql, sql, collation, database-table

I have tables with `latin1_swedish_ci` column. I've done tests and inserted into them some texts in languages like french, greek, japanese, spanish and it's working fine.
Data written in japanese for example (ぴゃ) are well stored and display.
I don't use UTF-8 and don't want to use UTF-8.

Can I let `latin1_swedish_ci` or should I use another type/Collation (text/latin1_swedish_ci) for storing texts which can be in many languages ?

Comment: Any reasons for not using utf8?I'm just asking ;)

Comment: "I don't use UTF-8 and don't want to use UTF-8." Why? That's what you _should_ be using - your tests are flawed, whether they work or not. Try `LIKE` and `ORDER BY` queries for instance.

Comment: @rkosegi I don't see any reason to use utf8 and I have issues with emacs to edit utf8 php files and display in browsers. 
When I will switch to utf8, I will swicth everything, php files, html outputs which are for now charset=iso-8859-1 and databases but I will have to fix many issues in order to.
@Mat I don't make any queries like `LIKE` or `ORDER BY` on these fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using anything but `utf8` is still okay. You just have to make sure that the connection you make to your database is made in the same collation.

Also, if you store unicode characters in non-unicode fields, you will face problems when you define indices on them, as the reference table for sorting and indexing the data will not reflect the correct character set.